# Webcam from worker thread

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, python-multithreading

Im using the following code to run webcam in background thread. I have to do heavy processing so I have done this hoping that it will improve the fps

```
import cv2
import time
from threading import Thread

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
threads = []

class WorkerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        print("start")
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('Face', frame)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print("Trying to open camera")
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            thread = WorkerThread()
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
            time.sleep(0.35)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
        cap.release()
```

the issue is that the frame is not visible. how can I make it visible?

Comment: *sigh* there's at least one every day. `imshow` without `waitKey`. Read the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow): "This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This the answer of your problem**

```
import cv2
import time
from threading import Thread

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
threads = []

class WorkerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        print("started")
        while True:            
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            cv2.imshow('Face', frame)
            k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
            if k == ord('q'):
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print("Trying to open camera")
        if(cap.isOpened()):
            thread = WorkerThread()
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
            time.sleep(0.35)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
        cap.release()
```

Comment: can you please help me to figure this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409937/opencv-streaming-is-too-laggy/45411033?noredirect=1#comment77783745_45411033

Comment: even if the prediction is slow, I want the video frame to be smooth

Comment: Code only answer with no explanation whatsoever. No test whether `cap.read()` succeeds or not. The misleading "Trying to open camera" is still way past the point where it actually happens (line 5). Pointless sleep. In vast majority of cases, it will never try to join the thread.