# Opencv streaming is too laggy

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I have retrained my model with tensorflow for poets inception model. It takes 0.4 seconds for predictions and 2 seconds for sorting. Since it takes a so long time, the frame is laggy and it is scrambled while predicting. Is there by any means that I can make frame smooth though the prediction takes time?
Following is my code...

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
               in tf.gfile.GFile('retrained_labels.txt')]

def grabVideoFeed():
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()
    return frame if grabbed else None

def initialSetup():
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    # This takes 2-5 seconds to run
    # Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('retrained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    print 'Took {} seconds to unpersist the graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

initialSetup()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    print 'Took {} seconds to feed data to graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

    while True:
        frame = grabVideoFeed()

        if frame is None:
            raise SystemError('Issue grabbing the frame')

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (299, 299), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

        cv2.imshow('Main', frame)

        # adhere to TS graph input structure
        numpy_frame = np.asarray(frame)
        numpy_frame = cv2.normalize(numpy_frame.astype('float'), None, -0.5, .5, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        numpy_final = np.expand_dims(numpy_frame, axis=0)

        start_time = timeit.default_timer()

        # This takes 2-5 seconds as well
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'Mul:0': numpy_final})

        print 'Took {} seconds to perform prediction'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

        start_time = timeit.default_timer()

        # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

        print 'Took {} seconds to sort the predictions'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))

        print '********* Session Ended *********'

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            sess.close()
            break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dat-tran is correct ,Although fater rcnn is fast but it will also lags somewhat.For no lag you can use yolo, ssd models,  i have used yolo it is good.

for Queues and Multiprocessing you can use following code.

```
from utils import FPS, WebcamVideoStream
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool

def worker(input_q, output_q):
     os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
     start_time = timeit.default_timer()
     # This takes 2-5 seconds to run
     # Unpersists graph from file

     graph_def = tf.Graph()
     with graph_def.as_default():
        graph_def_ = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.FastGFile('retrained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
            graph_def_.ParseFromString(f.read())
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def_, name='')

        sess = tf.Session(graph=graph_def)

    fps = FPS().start()
    while True:
        fps.update()
        frame = input_q.get()
         numpy_frame = np.asarray(frame)
         numpy_frame = cv2.normalize(numpy_frame.astype('float'), None, -0.5, .5, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
         numpy_final = np.expand_dims(numpy_frame, axis=0)

         start_time = timeit.default_timer()

         # This takes 2-5 seconds as well
         predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'Mul:0': numpy_final})

         print 'Took {} seconds to perform prediction'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

         start_time = timeit.default_timer()

         # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
         top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

        print 'Took {} seconds to sort the predictions'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))

        output_q.put(frame)

    fps.stop()
    sess.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_q = Queue(maxsize=10)
    output_q = Queue(maxsize=10)

    process = Process(target=worker, args=((input_q, output_q)))
    process.daemon = True
    pool = Pool(1, worker, (input_q, output_q))

    video_capture = WebcamVideoStream(src=0,
                                       width=args.width,
                                       height=args.height).start()

    fps = FPS().start()

    while (video_capture.isOpened()):
        _,frame = video_capture.read()
        input_q.put(frame)
        cv2.namedWindow('Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.resizeWindow('Image', 600, 600)
        cv2.imshow('Image', output_q.get())
        fps.update()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    fps.stop()
```

Comment: im getting this error `input_q = Queue(maxsize=args.queue_size)
NameError: name 'args' is not defined
`

Comment: as you are not providing those value in argument

Comment: now it is firing `   process = Process(target=worker, args=((input_q, output_q)))
NameError: name 'worker' is not defined
`

Comment: worker is your function in which you will execute your main code

Comment: Im so basic in python. can you please provide that function as well. it will save my life

Comment: i tried creating a function worker. It fires `ttributeError: Can't get attribute 'worker' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>`

Comment: I have edited code with worker function didnt checked you may have to do some addition/modification

Comment: thank you but still the camera is laggy even after this approach :(

Comment: it still takes 2 seconds

Comment: totally there is 2 sec lag for each frame

Comment: it will take 2 second as you didnt changed your model.

Comment: changing the model means?

Comment: model you used to create retrained_graph.pb

Comment: i changed it to optimized_gender.pb

Comment: prediction will take 2 second in each thread so if you are using 4 tread you can process 4 frame simoultaneously.

Comment: I dont know why your system is taking 2 second may be due to system resource limitation.

Comment: if you are trying to find objects in video please use @dat-tran blog

Comment: oaky... i find it still laggy

Comment: i already told you it will lag if you want no lag please use yolo model but its accuracy is little less but its okay.

Comment: can we retrain yolo

Comment: how do i do prediction  once in every 3 sec

Answer (score 0):

The problem because this is too laggy is due to the model that you used. Those models are not made for low latency. One way to make your frame smoother is to you models like Mobilenets or F-RCNN which are faster but have lower accuracy. In case, you're interested I [blogged about this on Medium](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/building-a-real-time-object-recognition-app-with-tensorflow-and-opencv-b7a2b4ebdc32).

Another option if you still want to use your model is to use Queues and Multiprocessing. You could set up one queue which loads in the image and one queue which only does the prediction before the other queue is loaded. At the end those two queues need to be sync together.

Comment: Can you please provide a gist on how I can use queue and multiprocessing?

Comment: a sample example will help a lot

Comment: In the blog article, I'm also providing code. Can you have a look at this? I'm using queues as well.

Comment: it is throwing an error like `ttributeError: Can't get attribute 'worker' on <module '__main__' (built-in)> Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module`

Comment: May i know how can  i use it with respect to my code please